# How can I authenticate users with Feathers.js

Tags: vue.js, feathersjs, feathers-vuex

I'm trying to log in a user using the vuex store.

```
onSubmit() {
  this.$store
    .dispatch("auth/authenticate", {
      username: "Sibi",
      password: "123",
      strategy: "local"
    })

    .then(function(result) {
      console.log("Authenticated!", result);
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.error("Error authenticating!", error);
    });
}
```

[image: I get a 401 error]

I have followed the docs and everything seems to be working for the signup.
Even if I hardcode the username and password it still shows Invalid

Comment: Check out the config in `default.json` (see https://github.com/feathersjs/feathers-chat/blob/8030e2535e28c600e06fc7a23f87fe8236851815/config/default.json#L33-L36) . Check if you did change the `usernameField` is set to `username`

Comment: it is : "local": {
      "usernameField": "username",
      "passwordField": "password"
    }